# Explicit map between $\check{H}^1(M,\underline{\mathbb{R}})$ and $H^1(M,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Is there a way to construct an explicit isomorphism between Cech cohomology and singular cohomology on a smooth manifold for degree 1? If yes can this be extended to higher degee?

Comment: I believe that this is done in "Principles of algebraic geometry" by Griffiths and Harris. See page 42.

Comment: @user2520938 thanks I'll check this out

Comment: If you are already accepting the fact that Cech and derived functor cohomology coincide, then it follows from the Poincare lemma that $\check{H}^i(M,\underline{\mathbb{R}})$ is equal to de Rham cohomology. At that point the de Rham theorem and its explicit construction can be invoked to relate this to singular cohomology.